# Spring boot API consume external API protected by Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, consumer

I'm building a Spring Boot API that should consume payload (JSON) from an external API. The external API is protected by Authentication maybe OAuth2, I don't know. All I have for authentication ist following information:

```
client-Id
client-secret
api-key: the API Key must be given to the header
grant_type: client_credentials
token-url: ..../login
```

With postman I get the access token as follow:

To body (JSON):

```json
{
    "username": "client-Id",
    "password": "client-Id",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

To header prop:

```
api-key: key
```

Now I want to implemented a function in my API to get the access token. I have try it with Spring OAuth2 client, but I get the error "401: No body found".

My Implementation look like this:

In the application prop. I put the relevant information:

```yaml
client:
  registration:
    name: app
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          app:
            client-id: id
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: read
        provider:
          app:
            token-uri: https://..../login
secret:
  admin:
    api:
      key: key
```

The Token class:

```java
@Component
public class MyToken {

    @Value("${client.registration.name}")
    private String clientRegistrationName;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.app.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationName).principal(clientId).build();


//--> here I get the Exception 401: No body found
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);
        
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();


        return accessToken.getTokenValue();
    }
```

The OAuth2AuthorizeClientManager class:

```java
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthorizeClientManager {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                 OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

I assume that the body with the credential and the header with the api-key are missing. But I don't know how to pass the information to the request? Maybe my approach is completely wrong.
Have anybody a idea to fix this or maybe another approach what I can try?

Thank you in advance.